# PHP Enconding - Formatting cedilla in Portuguese-BR is not working

Tags: php, html, utf-8, character-encoding

I'm facing an issue related to charset formatting words in Portuguese-BR which has **cedilla** in it.
When I set `setlocale` to 'portuguese-brazil' with `utf-8` enconding, PHP seems not understanding it.
As the image shows bellow, I try to convert the current month in English to Portuguese:

[image]

As we can see, the value above should show **Março** (which means **March** in English) to the final user.
I tried to navigate through Stack Overflow in Portuguese and here, but none of those questions and solutions worked for me.

In my HTML file, my `meta` tag is defined as following:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

The file it self was saved by `UTF-8 w/o BOM` formatted as well.

The snippet code which show this month:

```
<div id="ow-marketplace" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 table-responsive">
    <?php 
        setlocale( LC_ALL, 'pt_BR', 'pt_BR.utf-8', 'portuguese-brazilian' );
        date_default_timezone_set( 'America/Sao_Paulo' );
        $data = strftime( '%B/%y', strtotime('today'));
        echo "<h4 class=\"page-header\">Vendas Atuais do mês de ". ucfirst($data) ."</h4>";
    ?>
<div class="box-content">
```

I don't know how can I solve this problem, but I think charset seems not working as expected.
Can anyone help me with this?

If I need to post any further information, please advise me

Comment: Try this:
setlocale(LC_CTYPE, 'pt_BR');
date_default_timezone_set ("America/Sao_Paulo");

Encoding problems are certain headache for us, Brazilians. Good luck!

Comment: This doesn't work @LéoMuniz. PHP didn't translate month. It shows **March/15**. Damn it. Is this a bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most likely problem is your locale. PHP will try to set the locales in the given order, setting the first one it can find. If `pt_BR` is not using UTF-8 on your system, your results won't be UTF-8 encoded. Since you're trying `pt_BR.utf-8` as the second choice, PHP may be preferring the non-UTF-8 version over it.

1. Check what locales you have installed:

   ```
   $ locale -a
   ```

   For Windows, look here:
   https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/39cwe7zf%28v=vs.90%29.aspx
   (unconfirmed information, I don't know if there's a more Windows-y way to do this).
2. Prefer UTF-8 locales first:

   ```
   setlocale(LC_ALL, 'pt_BR.utf-8', 'pt_BR', 'portuguese-brazilian');
   ```
3. Test what locale was actually chosen:

   ```
   echo setlocale(..);
   ```

Comment: Actually, I tried to defined `pt_BR.utf-8` as the first in this order. Even I tried to define only `pt_BR.utf-8` PHP doesn't not showing exactly charset formatted. Additionally, when I echoed setlocation() in my browser, it shows `Portuguese_Brazil.1252`. At least, `locale -a ` showed me this: 
`pt_BR
pt_BR.iso88591
pt_BR.utf8
`. What could something go wrong?

Comment: Yes, you have not used the actual correct locale name.

Comment: Actually I using actual locale name, but even check with these steps, PHP still doesn't formatting charset correctly.

Comment: Did you? Your system says the locale is named `pt_BR.utf8`, but you've used `pt_BR.utf-8` in your code.

Comment: Well... now I saw this little difference. But, my website works on both **Linux** and **Windows**. In Linux I fixed this issue, but in Windows I still having problem with that. Any suggestion what could be? I checked the system locale and nothing happened.

Comment: I'm not sure how locales work on Windows, sorry. If Windows does offer a UTF-8 pt-br locale of some sort, you'll just have to list it right after `pt_BR.utf8` in your `setlocale` call.

Comment: Ok... Using your procedure to fetch system locale (in linux) for windows, I found `'pt-br'` which PHP doesn't understand though. I've found a documentation from Microsoft in this [LINK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/39cwe7zf%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) which points to `ptb` and `'portuguese-brazilian'`. Both recognize by PHP but not formatting cedilla correctly. I don't know if there is an conflict with UTF-8 charset, but I forced to use `utf8_encode()` method to make it works.

Comment: Note that if Linux returns UTF-8 encoded data and Windows doesn't, you'll need to `utf8_encode` or not depending on the environment. That's quite annoying, but inevitable.